# android - loading indicator in loopj

Tags: android, listview, loading

I'm using loopj library to parse JSON and then to inflate ListView (I do it in onSuccess). It takes about 2-3 seconds to load data and this time the screen is empty. How to show Loading indicator using this lib while loading? (I'm about abstract loading indicator, without showing current progress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Create a progress before hitting server like:-

```
ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        progress.setIndeterminate(false);
        progress.setCancelable(false);
```

2-Show progress before api call like :-

```
progress.show();
    AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();

    asyncHttpClient.get(String.format("url", ), new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable arg0, String arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onFailure(arg0, arg1);
                    progress.dismiss();
                }
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statuscode, String messsage) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onSuccess(statuscode, messsage);
                    progress.dismiss();
               }
          });
        }
```

Comment: it helped, thanx a lot!

Comment: so if I had 1000 different call method, I have to add ```progress.dismiss()``` 1000 times? Is there a way to add it globally?